# SQL query uses a lot of CPU and takes too long time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-design

I have an app where you can swipe you to matches like Tinder. On the swipe page you should see all the users that you have not swiped before.

I have these 4 tables. `Users`, `Matches`, `SwipedNo` and `SwipedYes`. It is checked whether the user is under `swipedNo`, `swipedYes` or `matches`. If the user is not in one of these tables, the user must be displayed.

**Users:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `landcode` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `code` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `codeExpires` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `bio` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastActive` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

**SwipedNo/SwipedYes:**

```
CREATE TABLE `swipedNo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user1` (`user1`,`user2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

**Matches:**

```
CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `dato` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user1` (`user1`,`user2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

I made this SQL query but it uses a lot of CPU and takes an average of 10 seconds.

```
SELECT id, name, birth, gender, newUser, distance FROM 

    (SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.birth,
    u.gender,
    u.newUser,
    (
        6371 *
       acos(cos(radians(55.6)) * 
       cos(radians(u.latitude)) * 
       cos(radians(u.longitude) - 
       radians(12.5)) + 
       sin(radians(55.6)) * 
       sin(radians(u.latitude )))
    ) AS distance
    FROM users u
    
    LEFT JOIN
    
    (SELECT 
    swipes.user1,
    swipes.user2

    FROM users u
    
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT user1, user2 FROM swipedNo
    UNION
    SELECT user1, user2 FROM swipedYes
    UNION
    SELECT user1, user2 FROM matches
    UNION
    SELECT user2, user1 FROM matches)

    as swipes ON swipes.user2 = u.id
    
    WHERE   
    swipes.user1=71211776843542) as outerSwipes ON outerSwipes.user2 = u.id
    
    WHERE
    outerSwipes.user2 IS NULL) as outerUsers
    WHERE
    outerUsers.distance <= 150
    LIMIT 200
```

EXPLAIN for the given query:

[image: Query explain image]

I hope you have some advice that can help reduce CPU consumption and the execution time.

Comment: Did the proposed query help? Could you share the `Explain` for the query in the answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

From a performance standpoint and the details provided in the question, it is difficult to replicate your environment or scenario. A benchmark data set and system requirements would need to be provided.

However, if you would like alternative suggestion on query design. Then you may share your performance metrics for the query below:

```
-- the user that new interactions are sought for
-- user id to ignore : 71211776843542
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT u.id,
               u.name,
               u.birth,
               u.gender,
               -- this column does not exist in the schema shared
               -- 
               -- u.newUser, 
               ( 6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(55.6)) * COS(RADIANS(u.latitude)) * COS
                             (
                                           RADIANS(u.longitude) - RADIANS(12.5))
                             +
                                      SIN(RADIANS(55.6)) * SIN(
                                      RADIANS(u.latitude))) )
                      AS
               distance
        FROM   users u
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT id
                           FROM   swipedno
                           WHERE  ( user1 = 71211776843542
                                    AND user2 = u.id )
                               OR ( user2 = 71211776843542
                                    AND user1 = u.id )
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT id
                           FROM   swipedyes
                           WHERE  ( user1 = 71211776843542
                                    AND user2 = u.id )
                               OR ( user2 = 71211776843542
                                    AND user1 = u.id )
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT id
                           FROM   matches
                           WHERE  ( user1 = 71211776843542
                                    AND user2 = u.id )
                               OR ( user2 = 71211776843542
                                    AND user1 = u.id ))) t
WHERE  t.distance < 150
LIMIT  200
```